# How can I use user input to call functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

I want to call a function using a user input. A user will be asked to choose from n = which will call a function that will create a new line and d which will call another function that will delete a line from the user input. And if the user input is not in the choices it will go back to the choices.

And I need to create a function using 'del' keyword in order to delete the line. But i don't have any idea how to do that.

```
def add(n):
    lines = list()
    add_line = input('Add a line: ')
    while add_line != '#':
        lines.append(add_line)
        add_line = input('Add a line: ')
    for line in lines:
        print(lines.index(line) +1, end = '')
        print(":", line)

def delete(d):


def main():
    choice= input ("Command n, d: ")
    for a in choice:
        add(n)

main()
```

my output should look like this:

```
Command n, d : n
Add a line: It is a lovely morning
Add a line: #
1: It is a lovely morning


Command n, d: d
Line number: 3
1: It is a lovely morning
2: for reading a book
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `lines` global or pass it to the delete function.

```
lines = list() # move this out of add
def delete():
    global lines 
    line_no = input('line number to delete: ')
    del lines[int(line_no) - 1]

def main():
    choice = input ("Command n, d: ")
    if "a" in choice:
        add()
    elif "d" in choice:
         delete()

main()
```

Comment: hmm, i've tried this but its giving me an error that the inputs that I enter are not defined .

Comment: now it did not call the function. if i try the for loop it calls the function but my problem is that when I put d in user input it Prints from the add not straight to the delete